# How to draw custom yahoo finance stock graph

Tags: ios, iphone, graph, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am new to the iOS graph apps world. I want to make a custom graph in my iPhone app through yahoo finance API. The Core requirements of my app are
1). To show instant stock price fluctuations in graph ranging from 1 day to 1 year as yahoo finance shows in its own website for any company.
2). To show a customised graph (graph line and background color) based on the values.
After doing some research on internet I have found two ways of doing it but both of them fulfil only one functional requirement and lack the other one.
1). To use YQL to retrieve stock values on daily basis. For this i am using a query like:
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "AAPL" and startDate = "2013-09-09" and endDate = "2013-10-10"&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

This feed gives stock details on daily basis. By parsing the response from above feed, I can fulfil my requirement number 2 but i need to show instant fluctuations because user can opt to view graph of single day. How can I show instant fluctuations if i go with this option? what will be the suitable yahoo finance URL for that?

2). To using following yahoo finance charts library.
https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/miscapiImageDownload

This API fulfils my functional requirement number 1 but this API returns an image and does not provide any option to change graph line color or background color. So if I go with this option, how can I customise the graph? Please Help!!!!

Comment: You can't get instant price data without paying for access to it...

Comment: @Wain. Is it written anywhere? can you provide me a link as a proof. Thanks.

Comment: @Wain is correct. Go look at Bloomerberg or Dow - you pay to get a feed or raw instantious transactions. Recall there is no "current price" - what you get is a stream of transactions, and as ones for one stock edge up or down the "current price" edges up and down. As far as charting goes, you can look at "Core Plot" on google.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks. Can you please provide me the link where I can buy that API for instantaneous transaction of stock details for a company?

Comment: I really don't know where or how - all I know is that it costs a fair amount of money. This question has come up before, and its why all "public" interfaces are 20 minutes or so delayed - to keep up the demand for the paid for services.I see some interesting feeds googling on "how to get a real time stock data".

Comment: David. Ok. Thanks a lot. I think google is the last hope now.